# Inserting grades and GPA not working for student

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

My code asks me to enter names from a .txt file then if the names are valid i can log in.

I have done this so far. Once i have successfully logged in I can press option 2 to add a new student. Now I have made a mistake for option 3. Option 3 asks me to enter a grade for the student. After hitting option 3 it asks me for the grade, whenever I enter a grade the program just crashes on me. I want it to display a GPA. And all the grades that were received. Which is what I wrote in my code. I am not sure where I made a mistake in my algorithm.

```
//This is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Constants used in the application */
const char * PASSWORD_FILE = "passwords.txt";
const int MAX_STUDENTS = 1000;
const int MAX_GRADES = 100;
const int MAX_CHARS = 25;

//Function to print Author Info
void printAuthorInfo();

//Function to display initial Menu and Get the User's Selection
int showMainMenu();

//Function to Login to the System
int login();

//member menu
int memberMenu();

//Enter GPA for current Student
void enterGPA(char ids[1000][25], float grades[1000][100], int[], int);

//Display student records to stdout
void print(char[1000][25], char[1000][25], char[1000][25], float[1000][100],     
int[], int);

//Save Records to File
void save(char[1000][25], char[1000][25], char[1000][25], float[1000][100],     
int[], int);

//Load Records from File
void load(char fn[1000][25], char ln[1000][25], char ids[1000][25], float   
grades[1000][100], int counts[], int num);

int main()
{
int loggedIn = 0;
int choice, subChoice;
char firstNames[1000][25];
char lastNames[1000][25];
char ids[1000][25];
float grades[1000][100];
int numGrades[1000];
char fn[25];
char ln[25];
int numStudents = 0;

//Top Level Loop
do {
    //display menu and get the user's selection
    choice = showMainMenu();

    if (choice == 0)
    {
        printf("Thank you for using our Application! GoodBy!");
    }
    else if (choice == 1)
    {
        printAuthorInfo();
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        loggedIn = login();

        if (loggedIn == 1)
        {
            printf("Welcome! You are now Logged In\n");

            //Interact with the user
            do
            {
                subChoice = memberMenu();

                if (subChoice == 1)
                {
                    printAuthorInfo();
                }
                else if (subChoice == 2)
                {
                    printf("Enter First Name: ");
                    scanf("%s", firstNames[numStudents]);
                    printf("Enter Last Name: ");
                    scanf("%s", lastNames[numStudents]);
                    printf("Enter Student ID: ");
                    scanf("%s", ids[numStudents]);
                    numStudents++;
                    printf("Student Has been added to System");
                }
                else if (subChoice == 3)
                {
                    enterGPA(ids, grades, numGrades, numStudents);
                }
                else if (subChoice == 4)
                {
                    print(firstNames, lastNames, ids, grades, numGrades, 
numStudents);
                }
                else if (subChoice == 5)
                {
                    void save(firstNames, lastNames, ids, grades, counts, 
numStudents);
                }
                else if (subChoice == 6)
                {
                    load(firstNames, lastNames, ids, grades, numGrades, 
&numStudents);
                }
                else if (subChoice == 7)
                {
                    printf("\nYou are logged Out Now");
                }
                printf("\n");
            } while (subChoice != 7);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Login Failed - Try again");
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
 } while (choice != 0);


system("pause");
return 0;
}

void printAuthorInfo()
{
 printf("Author Information\n");
 printf("Author Name: %s\n", "myinfo ");
 printf("Student ID: %s\n", "12345");
}

int showMainMenu()
{
//User Selection
int choice;

do
{
    //Display menu
    printf("Press 0 to exit\n");
    printf("Press 1 for Author Info\n");
    printf("Press 2 for Login\n");
    printf("Enter choice? ");

    //Read the selection
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    printf("\n");
 } while (choice < 0 || choice > 2);

//Return selection
return choice;
}

int login()
{
//Get User's username and password
char username[30];
char password[30];
char usernameInFile[30];
char passwordInFile[30];
int valid = 0;

//Prompt and get Username
printf("Enter Username: ");
scanf("%s", username);

//Prompt and get Password
printf("Enter Password: ");
scanf("%s", password);

//Open the input file
FILE * fptr = fopen(PASSWORD_FILE, "r");

while (fscanf(fptr, "%s %s", usernameInFile, passwordInFile) == 2)
{
    if (strcmp(username, usernameInFile) == 0 && strcmp(password, 
passwordInFile) == 0)
    {
        valid = 1;
    }
}

fclose(fptr);
return valid;
}


int memberMenu()
{
int choice = 0;

do
{
    printf("Press 1 for author info\n");
    printf("Press 2 to Enter new student\n");
    printf("Press 3 to enter grade for existing student\n");
    printf("Press 4 to print student records\n");
    printf("Press 5 to save student records\n");
    printf("Press 6 to load student records\n");
    printf("Press 7 to logout\nEnter Selection? ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    printf("\n");

 } while (choice < 1 || choice > 7);

 return choice;
 }

void print(char fn[1000][25], char ln[1000][25], char ids[1000][25], float  
grades[1000][100], int counts[], int num)
{
int i, j;
float sum, avg;
sum = 0;
avg = 0;

printf("%-15s %-15s %-10s %-8s %-8s\n", "First Name",
    "Last Name", "Std ID", "GPA", "Grades");

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    printf("%-15s %-15s %-10s", fn[i], ln[i], ids[i]);

    for (j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++)
    {
        sum += grades[i][j];
    }

    avg = sum / counts[i];
    sum = 0;
    printf("%-8.2f", avg);
    for (j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++)
    {
        printf("%-6.2f", grades[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
 }

void save(char fn[1000][25], char ln[1000][25], char ids[1000][25], float   
grades[1000][100], int counts[], int num)
{
int i, j;
float sum, avg;
char fname[100];
sum = 0;
avg = 0;

//Get file name
printf("Enter Output File Name: ");
scanf("%s", fname);

FILE * fptr = fopen(fname, "w");

fprintf(fptr, "%d\n", num);
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    fprintf(fptr, "%s %s %s %d ", fn[i], ln[i], ids[i], counts[i]);

    for (j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++)
    {
        fprintf(fptr, "%.2f ", grades[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fptr, "\n");
}

fclose(fptr);
}

void load(char fn[1000][25], char ln[1000][25], char ids[1000][25], float 
grades[1000][100], int counts[], int * num)
{
char fname[100];
int cur = *num;
int i, j, n, numStudents = 0;
float grade;

//prompt and get input file
printf("Enter Input File Name: ");
scanf("%s", fname);

//open file to read
FILE * fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
fscanf(fptr, "%d", &numStudents);
for (i = 0; i < numStudents && cur < 1000; i++)
{
    fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %s %d", fn[cur], ln[cur], ids[cur], &n);
    for (j = 0; j < n && counts[i] < 100; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fptr, "%f", &grade);
        grades[i][counts[i]] = grade;
        counts[i] += 1;
    }
    cur += 1;
}

*num = cur;
fclose(fptr);

}

void enterGPA(char ids[1000][25], float grades[1000][100], int counts[], int 
num)
{
char id[25];
int i, idx;
float gpa;

idx = -1;

printf("Enter Student ID: ");
scanf("%s", id);

//find student
for (i = 0; i < num && idx == -1; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(id, ids[i]) == 0)
    {
        idx = i;
    }
}

if (idx >= 0)
{
    printf("Enter Grade: ");
    scanf("%f", &gpa);
    grades[idx][counts[idx]] = gpa;
    counts[idx] += 1;
}
else
{
    printf("NO Such Student Exist In The System");
}
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free debugging service. It's not meant for you to just dump your whole program and expect someone else to debug for you. Learn for yourself [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - start by using a debugger.

Comment: If you really need help here then please provide a [mcve]. That is, remove all code that isn't needed to reproduce the problem whilst still keeping the code complete enough to reproduce the problem. You may even find the cause of your problem yourself whilst doing that (many professional programmers use that very technique as one way of debugging).

Comment: `grades[i][counts[i]] = grade;` : Check `counts[i]`. I think `int numGrades[1000];` isn't initialize. You use uninitialize value.

Comment: How would i solve this problem? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: try `int numGrades[1000];` --> `int numGrades[1000] = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

> `grades[i][counts[i]] = grade;` : Check `counts[i]`. I think `int numGrades[1000];` isn't initialize. You use uninitialize value.
>                       – BLUEPIXY

BLUEPIXY is quite right, only the line above is in function `load()`, while running with `valgrind` reveals that for option 3 there's the same problem in function `enterGPA()`:

```
    grades[idx][counts[idx]] = gpa;
```

> try `int numGrades[1000];` --> `int numGrades[1000] = {0};`
>                       – BLUEPIXY

This indeed solves the problem in all places.